# Slide specific Fieldset using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following html with two fieldsets..I want to provide toggleSlide functionality to those fieldsets which contains  ..if any fieldset which doesnt contain div tag with the id "contents" shud not slide. I would appreciate if someone can provide Fiddler.

**The HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Collapse fieldset when legend element clicked</title>  
</head>
<body>
  <fieldset><legend>Awesome</legend>
    <div id="contents">
    <p>
      HELLO THERE
    </p>
    <p>
      Awesome
    </p>
    awesome
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <fieldset><legend>Awesome 2</legend>
    <p>
      HELLO THERE
    </p>
    <p>
      Awesome
    </p>
    awesome
  </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

**The Script**

```
$("fieldset legend").click(function() { 
  if ($(this).parent().children().length == 2)
   $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow");
  else
  {
    $(this).parent().wrapInner("<div>");
    $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().parent());
    $(this).parent().find("div").toggle();
  }
});
```

Comment: Fiddler? Or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:-

I have changed `id="contents"` to `class="contents"` since id must be unique and it seems like are looking to have multiple `id="contents"` which will make the html invalid. if not you can just use `$(this).closest('fieldset').find('#contents').length == 0` in the first line of click callback.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QeZn7/)

```
$("fieldset legend").click(function () {

    if ($(this).closest('fieldset').find('.contents').length == 0) return;
    if ($(this).parent().children().length == 2) $(this).siblings().slideToggle("slow");
    else {
        $(this).parent().wrapInner("<div>");
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().parent());
        $(this).parent().find("div").toggle();
    }
});
```

#### Html

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Awesome</legend>
    <div class="contents">
        <p>HELLO THERE</p>
        <p>Awesome</p>awesome</div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Awesome 2</legend>
    <p>HELLO THERE</p>
    <p>Awesome</p>awesome</fieldset>
```

Comment: +1, but I'd do the `closest('fieldset')` search above the click event. `var f = $(...).closest('fieldset'); f.click(....);`.